# Installation process of utPLSQL

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, plsql, utplsql

I am trying to setup utPLSQL for writing a unit test for PLSQL project.
I am running into error while installing.
I am not getting how to install it. 
Could anyone give a step by step procedure to install utPLSQL ?

Thanks

Comment: The documentation looks pretty thorough.  Did you see the Readme.txt and the Getting Started webpage (started.html)?

Comment: Yes I did. The ut_i_do install is not working

Comment: What are the error messages or incorrect behavior you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

From http://utplsql.sourceforge.net/Doc/fourstep.html

It looks rather simple, but you must connect to [sqlplus](/questions/tagged/sqlplus) as `SYSTEM` - a power user on your database that will be able to create the `UTP` user.

```
SQL> connect system/< the system's password >

SQL> create user utp identified by utp default tablespace
       users temporary tablespace temp;

SQL> grant create session, create table, create procedure,
      create sequence, create view, create public synonym, drop public synonym to utp;

SQL> alter user utp quota unlimited on users;
```

Then only run

```
SQL> ut_i_do install
```

Comment: ut_i_do install  is not found. SQL> ut_i_do_install
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "ut_i_do_in..." - rest of line ignored.